# saving data in many to many table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database

I am trying to setup a Many to Many relational database but i get error 500,  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) at editor: 1

i send a payload with this to the route:
componentList: [1, 2, 3]
configuration: 1

But i simply cant seem to understand the logic here. As i save a new Configuration and are syncing the relationships to the components?

```
class Component extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['url', 'category'];

    public function belongsSofa(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Sofa::class, 'component_sofa', 'components_id', 'sofas_id');
    }

    public function belongsConfiguration(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Configuration::class, 'component_configuration', 'components_id', 'configuration_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Configuration extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['configuration'];

    public function owner(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            \App\Models\User::class,
            'by_user_id' //custom name
        );
    }
    public function belongsComponent(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Configuration::class, 'component_configuration', 'configuration_id', 'components_id');
    }
}
```

component:

```
<template>
   <button @click="postConfiguration">post</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {

   data() {
       return {
           configuration: 1,
           componentList: [1,2,3],
       };
   },
   methods: {
       postConfiguration() {
           const data = {
               configuration: this.configuration,
               componentList: this.componentList,
           };
           axios.post(route('editor.store'), data)
       }
   },
};
</script>
```

route

`Route::post('/editor', [EditorController::class, 'store'])->name('editor.store');`

controller

````
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // This is the data sent in the request body
        $configuration = new Configuration;
        $configuration->value = $request->input('configuration');
        $configuration->save();

        $componentIds = $request->input('componentList');
        $configuration->components()->sync($componentIds);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Configuration and components saved successfully'
        ]);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: you don't have a relationship named `components`, you named it `belongsComponent` ... but you can always check your logs to see what is causing the 500

Comment: Oh thanks i guess i missed out on that part when going through a tutorial, but can you give a hint to where in the logs i might look for what is causing the error?

Comment: In your `storage/logs` you probably have a file with all the errors getting logged. It will even tell you what line  or method causes the errors

Comment: wow that is freaking amazing, !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BelongsToMany relationship, you should use plural form of model name, change:

```
class Component extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['url', 'category'];

    public function sofas(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Sofa::class, 'component_sofa', 'components_id', 'sofas_id');
    }

    public function configurations(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Configuration::class, 'component_configuration', 'components_id', 'configuration_id');
    }
}

class Configuration extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['configuration'];

    public function owner(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            \App\Models\User::class,
            'by_user_id' //custom name
        );
    }
    public function components(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Configuration::class, 'component_configuration', 'configuration_id', 'components_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: i still get the error?
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) at editor: 1

Comment: Can you provide more errors in your question description?

Comment: after a good nights sleep i woke and found it was the "value" variable name that caused the bug, but thanks for the heelp